# POSITIVE_INFINITY comparison

Tags: java, double

can we compare POSITIVE_INFINITY of Double wrapper in Java?

Basically what would be the result of comparison between double a and double b, where both are set as Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY?

A related question, is <= relation a total order on double primitive in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<` and `>` don't form a total order, but `Double.compare` does.

`Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` compares as larger than anything but itself and `Double.NaN`.  If both are set as `Double.POSITIVE_INFINITY` they will compare as equal.